# What are different ways to backup and restore cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to backup the whole cluster consistently. What are different ways to backup and restore Cassandra cluster?

Comment: I *like* this question, because I'm thinking about different approaches, but it's not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the DataStax Enterprise version, then the easiest way is to perform the backups and restore using OpsCenter.

If you are using the DataStax Community or open-sourced version of Cassandra, then use `nodetool snapshot` to create backups of tables and/or keyspaces.

Please bear in mind that SSTables are immutable, i.e. they never change once they are written to disk. So unlike RDBMS data files, SSTables are not updated.

To perform a snapshot cluster-wide, use SSH tools such as pssh to perform parallel snapshots on all nodes.

More information on the `snapshot` utility is [available here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSnapShot.html).

There are several ways to restore from snapshots. One way is to re-load the data using the `sstableloader` tool where the data is read back into the cluster. Another way is by copying the SSTable directory from snapshot and running `nodetool refresh`. Finally, you can replace the existing data with the snapshot and restarting the node.

More information on backups and restores are [available here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html).